# How to launch com.google.android.GoogleCamera with specific mode

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am trying to start the Google Camera App. I am able to do this with the following code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.GoogleCamera", "com.android.camera.CameraActivity");
intent.setAction("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is, there is no possibility to swipe on the screen and select another camera mode.
When i set the action to:

```
  intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
```

I have the full working Google Camera App running, but how can I start the app with the mode IMAGE_CAPTURE or IMAGE_CAPTURE_HDR or VIDEO_CAPTURE?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please understand that relatively few devices have this app.

Comment: Yeah maybe...but whatever? :)
btw. just checked the play store. its 10-50 million downloads.

Comment: That represents less than 1-5% of Android devices. Moreover, your app has no way of requiring that this app be installed on any given device that has your app installed. As a result, you will either crash or simply fail to function on 95-99+% of Android devices.

Comment: yeah whatever. maybe one of the 1-5% can give me a usable answer ;)

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. Could you find a solution for this?